# How can I check 2 conditions in NumPy Arrays in Python?

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I have a numpy array named "a" and I want it to slice in a certain range like between 0.5 and 1.
How can I do that? This one doesn't work.

```
a[a <= 1 and a >= 0.5]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use bitwise operators:

```
a[(a <= 1) & (a >= 0.5)]
```

Comment: Uh I'd tried that one but i forgot to put those conditions in parentheses. Thank you, mb...